# Is there a way to do youtube live stream via another account

Tags: youtube, video-streaming, streaming, live

We have a situation where by a person should have a live streaming concert. We want this live happen via our youtube account.

We do not want to give our youtube account username and password to somebody else.

Is there a way to give some access/permission so that they can do live streaming via our channel?

Answer (score 0):

I am don't very good with it, but along to [article](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2907883?hl=en) you need to pass your youtube stream key to do what you want.
As I say, I don't know is it safety, but that way you don't share your username and password.